# Fixing footer to bottom in laravel bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't do something so simple and I'm pissed off. I am using bootstrap in Laravel. I need to set it up for mobile. The footer either hovers over the body or stays in the middle of the page. How can I solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  .main-footer{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-primary {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f6bd1f;
    border-color: #f6bd1f;
    box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
<!-- Site wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">

    <section class="content" style="padding-top: 7%;">   
      <style type="text/css">    
    body {
   background-image: url("https://example.com/../../.././dist/img/example.jpg") !important;
   background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><a href="https://example.com/sss"> <img style="max-width: 36px" src="https://example.com/../../.././previous.png"></a></div><div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -28px;">register</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="https://example.com/ddd">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="example">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control " name="first_name" value="" required autocomplete="first_name" autofocus>

                                                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->


  <footer class="main-footer" style="margin-left: 0px !important; position: relative;">
    <div class="float-right d-none d-xs-block">
      <b>Version</b> 4.0.8
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2018-2021 </strong> All rights
    reserved.
  </footer>

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="https://example.com/../../plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="https://example.com/../../dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="https://example.com/../../dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/../../plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/../../plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/../../plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/../../plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The button isn't visible.

[image: The button is not visible.]

position:fixed; and bottom:0; for Footer  If I say, the footer is fixed in the middle of the page.

Comment: Position fixed and bottom 0 will be showing your footer to the bottom of screen (viewport), not to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I had the same issue with fixed footer at bottom and its mainly due to html structure. This post has well explained [fixed bottom footer](https://matthewjamestaylor.com/bottom-footer)